# Why doesn't streaming a std::double_t to std::cout give me decimal places?

Tags: c++

I have this minimal code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::double_t> rationalNumbers;
    std::vector<std::string> input {"1", "2", "54"};
    for (auto &st : input) 
    {
        rationalNumbers.push_back((std::double_t) std::stod(st));
    }

    for (auto &number : rationalNumbers)
    {
        std::cout << "Number: " << number << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I print the `rationalNumbers` in the second loop I get

> Number: 1 Number: 2 Number: 54

Can some one tell me why the output is not

> Number: 1.0 Number: 2.0 Number: 54.0

Because they are not supposed to be integers anymore, otherwise it would be in conflict with `std::vector<std::double_t> rationalNumbers;` or am I wrong?

Comment: Change the `precision` if you want.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I did it like this `std::cout << std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double_t>::max_digits10) << "Number: " << number << std::endl;` but the result didn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is based on a false premise, that streaming a value of a floating-point type automatically gives you one decimal place. It does not, and it never has.

You are confusing type/form with *representation*. It is perfectly reasonable, under some conditions, to display the integer `1` in the same manner as the floating-point value `1.0`, given that these are the same number.

To get fixed-point representation, you could use `std::fixed`. Or explore some of the other [I/O manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). Ultimately, the manner in which this number is rendered is up to you.

Comment: I've missed the mentioned duplicate question. So my numbers in `rationalNumbers` are actually doubles (i.e.  x.0) because of `(std::double_t) std::stod(st)` and in order to see the fixed-point representation I just had to adjust the output, right?

Comment: @TalG: That's right. In fact, you didn't need the cast anyway; you're adding them to a container of `std::double_t` so `std::double_t`s are what it will contain - if there were no implicit conversion from `double` (which is what `std::stod(st)` gives you) to that then your program just wouldn't have compiled. (That being said, writing explicit code is not without its benefits even when technically redundant. YMMV.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So I could even use `std:stoi(st)` to read the string as integers and they would be converted implicitly to my container type which is of `std::double_t` in this case. Can you give me an example of an explicit conversion based on my code?

Comment: @TalG That's right. (An example of an explicit conversion is what you're already doing!)

Comment: Right, I got confused for a second  :D.